# Maintaing tree structure after child is deleted

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have used composite views to build tree structure using code given in following example.
http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/AdWjU/. Additionally my model contains index (1,1.1,1.2,1.3 etc) which I have set using some logic. Now I want to remove rows (parent and header). So when I remove any row I want to update the indexes of the remaining rows.

for ex:

```
 1. Root
   1.1 a
   1.2 b
   1.3 c
```

So if I remove 1.2 from above children, then indexes for remaining rows should be

```
 1. Root
   1.1 a
   1.2 c
```

I tried re-rendering view by binding event like :

```
  if (this.collection) {
            this.listenTo(this.collection, "remove", this.render);
  }
```

But it is not working as it is not maintaing the values I have entered(in textboxes of sibling rows).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are taking input from your textboxes and updating your models accordingly.  Then re-rendering won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the index is a property of your models, isn't the problem that you aren't updating the models when another is removed?

The following might be a useful starting point.

`this.listenTo(this.collection, 'remove', this.collection.updateIndexes.bind(this.collection));`